# Closing Dialog quits Application if QMainWindow is hidden

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following Problem:

I have a Qt MainWindow which starts several Dialogs. Through an external source, I can hide and show the MainWindow. If a dialog is open, only the MainWindow is hidden, but the dialog is still visible. This is not nice but not my main problem. The main problem is, if i close the dialog while the MainWindow is hidden, the whole Application terminates. I do not want that, because I can make my main window visible again by external source.

I know it has something to do with QApplication quitOnLastWindowClosed. But if i set it true, my Application doesn't terminate if i normaly press "X".

Here is an example:

```
// MainApp.h
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

class MainApp : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MainApp(QObject *parent = nullptr);
private slots:
  void slotOpenDialog();
private:
  QMainWindow mMainWindow;
  Ui::MainWindow mUi;
};

// MainApp.cpp
#include "MainApp.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QMessageBox>

MainApp::MainApp(QObject *parent) {
  mUi.setupUi(&mMainWindow);
  mMainWindow.show();

  connect(mUi.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainApp::slotOpenDialog);

  // simulate external hide and show mechanism
  QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout,
          [=] {
            if(mMainWindow.isHidden()) mMainWindow.show();
            else mMainWindow.hide();
          });
  timer->start(3000);
}

void MainApp::slotOpenDialog() {
  QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Info", "text");
}

// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainApp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainApp* mApp = new MainApp;
  // if set true, I can't exit the application with "X"
  //a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
  int error = a.exec();
  delete mApp;
  return error;
}
```

How can I prevent the program from quitting when it is hidden and a still visible dialog has been closed and how can I make it exit normally when the window is visible?

Comment: How about adding an invisible perhaps 1x1 window open in the background?

Comment: Oh no please not. My colleagues kill me when I suggest such a hack. :D

Comment: Right. It will have to be some hack anyway, since as far as I know, when you close all windows QT quits. Is it acceptable to run your application as a service? Maybe look here: https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions does it help?

Comment: The thing is, I do not understand the difference between hiding and closing. If all windows are hidden except one and the last visible window is closed, QT terminates the application. Why does qt not quit the application if only one window exists and it is hidden? Apparently QT makes no distinction between hidden and closed?!

Comment: QApplication emits a signal "lastWindowClosed" and it has a quit() slot. What about connecting your own slot onLastWindowClosed() to that signal and quitting only when you want to?

Comment: I agree on Benjamin's idea.

Comment: Yes, with this signal and a few other adjustments it is possible. Unfortunately, not a nice solution. Maybe it's also because of my ugly problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QApplication emits a signal "lastWindowClosed" and it has a `quit()` slot. As mentioned in the comments, the problem can be solved by connecting your own slot `onLastWindowClosed()` to that signal and quitting only when you want to.